# Powershell script foreach ($x in $y) not working correctly

Tags: powershell, automation

Just writing some basic scripts after avoiding PowerShell for too long and I'm getting kinda stuck here. Trying to pass multiple parameters to a single "argument" in a function but it will only ever return the first value in the string

```
#--------------------------------
# Returns logged on user of machine(s) given in parameter
#--------------------------------
function Get-UserLogged{
    param($computerName)
    foreach ($computer in $computerName) {

        return (query user /server:$computerName)
    }
}
```

Now if i call the function and run for example...

```
Get-UserLogged Server01 Server02 Server03
```

It will only return the output for server 1, so it seems that the foreach isn't working as expected

Different script same issue:

```
function p{
    param($computerName)

    foreach ($computer in $computerName) {

        return (test-connection $computer -Count 1)

    }

}
```

if I run:

```
p localhost, google.com, bbc.com
```

it will only attempt localhost

Comment: What type are these? Server01 Server02 Server03

Comment: Whatever is the default, I did try setting the parameter as both a string and array but got the same result

Comment: You shouldn't use the return statement.  Return tells PowerShell to exit the current function/script.  Instead, when you want to return multiple values simply invoke the command that would generate those values (e.g. in your examples above, remove the return statement and the round brackets).  Also, in your first example, the command inside your foreach statement uses $computerName (the collection that gets passed in) instead of just $computer (the item you are currently processing in the current iteration of the foreach loop).  Change those two things and you should be in much better shape.

Comment: @KirkMunro I'm not sure where you got that. It is one way return can work but not the only way. Return can be used to return a value from a function without issue or exiting the script.

Comment: @KirkMunro I have no idea why removing "return" works but it solved the issue... Thanks for your help

Comment: @AustinFrench The point being made was that return exits (in addition to outputting data), while simply outputting data does not.

The thing to note about the return statement is that it exits the scope in which it is contained after it returns whatever value it is told to return (assuming it is told to return a value).  It is also important to note that return isn't the only way to return data from a function.  See this discussion about best practices when returning values from PowerShell: [link](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/issues/46).

Comment: @KirkMunro `The thing to note about the return statement is that it exits the scope in which it is contained after it returns whatever value it is told to return (assuming it is told to return a value).` That's exactly as one would expect a return statement to work... His problem wasn't using return but using return incorrectly (inside a foreach).

Comment: @AustinFrench Apparently not.  Many people think they need to use return in PowerShell in order for a function/script to return data, and then run into this issue, which is why I explained how return works.  The OP didn't need to use return at all, so I disagree that his problem wasn't using return.

Answer (score 4):

You're referencing the array `$computerName` inside the loop, not the "current item", `$computer`.

```
function Get-UserLogged{
    param($computerName)
    foreach ($computer in $computerName) {

        query user /server:$computer
    }
}
```

To pass an array of strings to a parameter, use a comma to separate the items:

```
Get-UserLogged -computerName Server01, Server02, Server03
```

Comment: Thank you, so is the parameter an array by default or is it made an array when given more than just string with no spaces? I was under the impression it was a string by default and an array if you prefix it with an @

Comment: It's made an array by the comma. You haven't specified a type for the parameter in the `param()`-section, so when it's a single word (or quoted if you have a space in the value), powershell makes it a string. If you used `-computerName 1`, it would have been an `int`.

Comment: Actually still having the same issue after referencing the current item instead of the array. Can't test the Get-UserLogged as I don't have any servers at home but I tried it with a different script:


( Pasted code into original post as not sure about comment formatting)

Comment: `$computer` didn't work because you called it without a comma. so only `Server1` was passed to your "array" `$computerName`. `Server02` and `Server03` went to the arguments array `$args` as uncaught arguments. My answer is a two-part-solution :)

Comment: I believe I've fixed both of those things but still getting the same result, see edit in top post.

And thank you for your help, I'm not sure why I'm finding this so difficult, need to go and pick up a beginners book I think

Comment: You did notice that I removed `return` right? `return` would have stopped the whole function after the first computer.. You need to use the whole answer. :-)